# How do you pull specific row index numbers from an array with FOR loops?

Tags: php

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  The $numrows shows rows being counted, but nothing shows for the $Value1 $Value2 $Value3.

```
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost", username, password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 

catch (PDOException $e) 
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
$sql = "SELECT id 
        FROM table";

$result = $dbh->query($sql);
$numrows=$result->rowCount();
echo "Total ids found $numrows";

if ( $numrows > 0 )
{
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
            $Value1 = $result[$i]['id'];
            $Value2 = $result[$i + 1]['id'];
            $Value3 = $result[$i + 2]['id'];
            echo "Value1: $Value1 Value2: $Value2 Value3: $Value3";
    }

        Print '<br> test output';
}
```

Comment: looks like you are iterating indexes multiple times because of the $i+1 ; $i +2 .. maybe use $i+=3 in your for

Comment: What's weird is that I get nothing.  Nothing echos out at all.  Except for $numrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating indexes multiple times :

on the first run :

```
$i = 0;

$Value1 = $result[0]['id'];
$Value2 = $result[1]['id'];
$Value3 = $result[2]['id'];
```

on the second run :

```
$i = 1;

$Value1 = $result[1]['id'];
$Value2 = $result[2]['id'];
$Value3 = $result[3]['id'];
```

etc.

You could do :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i+=3)
```

Comment: Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [0] => 1
    [img] => images/img.jpg
    [1] => images/img.jpg)      It shows the array of values when I check.  Just no output on the screen when I echo it.  Weird

Comment: looks like a var_dump(), sure you didnt edit your code ?

Comment: var_dump =    object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(101) "SELECT id, FROM table" }         So it counts the numrows, but maybe PDO is not processing query?

Comment: echo shows nothing ? does your php settings show errors ?

Comment: I doesn't have any errors, just the var_dump doesn't look right.  Print_r also isn't showing the array = PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT id, img FROM table)     What gets me is that it did count the rows.

Comment: Foreach does work, but shows as array.  So this must be creating a multidimensional array.

Comment: $sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();       query can't do for() loops, it has to be a fetchAll().  That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`query` will not work for this FOR loop.  You have to use `fetchAll`.  Using 'singe batteur's excellent counting code, we can complete this code:

```
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */

//print_r($result);  //check to see an actual array
//var_dump($result);

$numrows=count($result);
echo "Total ids found $numrows<br>";

if ( $numrows > 0 )
{
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i+=3)
    {       $Value1 = $result[$i]['course_name'];
            $Value2 = $result[$i + 1]['course_name'];
            $Value3 = $result[$i + 2]['course_name'];
            echo "Value1: $Value1 Value2: $Value2 Value3: $Value3<br>";
    }

}
```